# Какой хеширующий алгоритм используется для хранения паролей в /etc/shadow?

Tags: linux, хеширование

Кажется в Linux пароли хранятся в файле `/etc/shadow`, точнее хранятся не сами пароли, а их хеши.

Какой хеширующий алгоритм используется при этом? Если это зависит от дистрибутива, то как узнать, какой хеширующий алгоритм используется в моём дистрибутиве?

Comment: https://www.slashroot.in/how-are-passwords-stored-linux-understanding-hashing-shadow-utils

Answer (score 2, accepted):

метод хэширования по умолчанию определён в файле `/etc/login.defs`

```
$ grep '^ENCRYPT_METHOD' /etc/login.defs
ENCRYPT_METHOD SHA512
```

он может быть переопределён в конфигурационных файлах *pam* (естественно, для тех программ, которые его используют). например, в дистрибутиве *debian gnu/linux* есть такая конфигурационная директива:

```
$ grep -r '^password.*pam_unix' /etc/pam.d/
/etc/pam.d/common-password:password [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure sha512
```

в этом примере метод совпадает с тем, что определён в `/etc/login.defs` — *sha512*.

---

но данные директивы повлияют только на хэши новых паролей. уже существующие (или вручную вписанные) могут использовать любой другой метод.

Answer (score 2):

Aлгоритм указан в самом хеше. Хеш имеет несколько "полей":
пусть хеш такой :
`kaktus:$1$jbdsfj$ewryh4hferf444f3w:213:3:123:6:8:17:`

`kaktus` это имя пользователя
сам хеш `$1$jbdsfj$ewryh4hferf444f3w` - делится на несколько секторов, разделяемых $ таким образом : `$id$salt$hashed`. 
`Id` описывает алгоритм хеширования:
`$1$` это MD5,
`$2a$` это Blowfish,
`$2y$` это Blowfish,
`$5$` это SHA-256,
`$6$` это SHA-512,
`salt` - соль, подробнее : [https://andreyex.ru/linux/kriptograficheskie-hesh-funktsii/\](https://andreyex.ru/linux/kriptograficheskie-hesh-funktsii/%5C)
`hashed` - выходное значение хеш функции

Далее `213` это дата последнего изменения пароля (в днях с 1 января 1970 )
Далее `3` минимально допустимое кол-во дней между сменами пароля
Далее `123` максимально допустимое кол-во дней между сменами пароля(через такое кол-во дней с момента установки пароля его необходимо обязательно сменить)
Далее `6` Кол-во дней, за которое пользователь получит предупреждение о смене пароля(см. предыдущий пункт)
Далее `8` Кол-во дней, в течение которых после истечения срока действия пароля учетная запись будет отключена.
Далее `17` Дата истечения срока действия учетной записи, выраженная в количестве дней с 1 января 1970 года.

Поправьте меня, если я где-то ошибся
Источники :

- комментарий Mike
- cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcshadow-file